# How do I disable jose4j log messages through my log4j config?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j, jose4j

I am using [jose4j](https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/wiki/Home) in a java application that I am working on. It is a json web token library, and I've found that putting the package name inside my log4j config file does nothing to quiet the (many) debug logging messages that I am seeing from this thing. Here's my relevant log4j config section

```
<Root level="debug">
    <AppenderRef ref="Console"></AppenderRef>
</Root>
<Logger name="org.jose4j" level="warn" additivity="false">
    <AppenderRef ref="Console"></AppenderRef>
</Logger>
```

So, I essentially only want to see log messages from jose4j when they rise to the level of warn (or more dire).

A few things I have been able to gather.

- Setting the root logger to "info" does make the jose4j debug messages go away, so jose4j's logger at least knows about my logging setup.
- It looks like the logger that jose4j uses is [org.sl4j](https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/src/78e92a06992392f8474746e6e96cf6cb389662d4/src/main/java/org/jose4j/jwa/AlgorithmAvailability.java?fileviewer=file-view-default)
- I had a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44576327/how-do-i-supress-log-messages-from-external-libraries-using-log4j/44585783?noredirect=1#comment76270323_44585783) yesterday. It seemed like adding a few jars did the trick to fix that issue, but I'm not having luck with this.

I also added [this jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl) to the classpath... this also did not work.

Does anyone know how I can get this library to work with my logging setup?

Comment: From the maven dependencies of jose4j (see http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.bitbucket.b_c%7Cjose4j%7C0.5.7%7Cjar), it looks like the logging system used by the SLF4J facade is Logback . So the configuration would probably have to be a logback.xml file.

Comment: Would I have to put this alongside my log4j config file? Is this possible?

Comment: You may test this at least to see if this config is taken into account by jose4j . Later it would be better that all classes use the same configuration, in that case for your custom libraries, either migrate your logging code to  SLF4J , or use the log4j-over-slf4j bridge, see here : https://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html

Comment: I added a logback.xml as seen [here](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html), but it doesn't seem to effect anything. Set the logback level to "warn"

Answer (score 0):

Two points:

- You need to have only **one** implementation of the slf4j interface. Just open the org.slf4j.spi.LoggerFactoryBinder and check the Type hierarchy (Ctrl-T in Eclipse).
- For log4j it has to be https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.25, for example.